# Save video stream into the database's table

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqldatatypes

I want to save a stream video into my database, I want to know what data type in SQL-Server is suitable to save video stream ?

**EDIT :** Note that, I'm using EF4 as my project ORM.

Any advice will be graceful.

Thanks.

Comment: any particular reason you want to save the video itself in the DB and not just a pointer to it (such as a file name)?

Comment: It's not a web-application, and the reason is I don't want users can directly access files. That's why I want to store them in Database.

Comment: If you don't want your users to be able to see the file, only play it, you'll have to use ISequentialStream and create your own player anyway.  EF won't help there... I would recommend storing it as a file, avoid lots of headache later (if fact, you'll be replacing one headache with another one, possibly smaller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing BLOBs such as video data you can use the `varbinary(MAX)` data type in SQL Server 2005 which is supported by Entity Framework.

Keep in mind whenever you load the entity that contains this column EF will try to fully load your full video into memory, there is no byte streaming mode in EF - this means not only will this not scale well but with multiple users also becomes infeasible because of the memory requirements and will perform poorly. Don't do this - I would look hard for better alternatives.

Comment: @s.amani: Fundamentally there is not much that can be done since this is a desktop application - the user already has access to your videos whether you like it or not. The only thing you can do is make it a bit harder, i.e. you could encrypt your video and decrypt as you stream or store just the video headers in a separate place and combine them with the rest of the video at runtime. Depending on the video file format this might or might not be feasible.

Comment: You suggested a fantastic tip, separate its data is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

we can assume that a video is basically a file and you can use the `FILESTREAM` SQL 2008 data type.

there should be plenty of examples around, I found this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/03/16/saving-and-retrieving-file-using-filestream-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm using SQL-Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

[Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/). The article shows how to use streaming semantics for large BLOBs (avoid creating an in memory byte[]) and you ca use the implementation in C# forms just as well, is nothing specific for ASP MVC or web in general.

Comment: Thank you Remus that was useful.